# Dynamodb: Can you format the output of Table.scan()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am playing around with DynamoDB and am looking into `Table.scan()` method. I have a table that contains simple information on some NFL players and a simple block of code to read the entries in that table:

```
table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('Players')

response = table.scan()
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

The output of this looks something like:

```
[{'JerseyNumber': Decimal('10'), 'PlayerLastName': 'Hill', 'PlayerFirstName': 'Tyreek', 'PlayerTeam': 'Dolphins', 'PlayerID': Decimal('7')}, 
{'JerseyNumber': Decimal('97'), 'PlayerLastName': 'Bosa', 'PlayerFirstName': 'Nick', 'PlayerTeam': '49ers', 'PlayerID': Decimal('8')}
```

Is there a way to format the output to look something more like:

```
JerseyNumber: 10
PlayerLastName: Hill
PlayerFirstName: Tyreek
PlayerTeam: Dolphins
PlayerID: 7
```

Comment: You'll need to format those yourself.  It's just JSON output.

Comment: You should probably consider storing the jersey number and player ID as strings, that happen to be numeric, rather than as numbers. Unless you're going to do some numeric calculations with them.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('Players')

response = table.scan()

players = response['Items']

for player in players:
    for key in player:
        print(f"{key}: {player[key]}")
```

Result is:

```
JerseyNumber: 10
PlayerLastName: Hill
PlayerFirstName: Tyreek
PlayerTeam: Dolphins
PlayerID: 7
JerseyNumber: 97
PlayerLastName: Bosa
PlayerFirstName: Nick
PlayerTeam: 49ers
PlayerID: 8
```

You can add newlines or other presentation formatting as needed.